# AngularJS change date format

Tags: angularjs

How can I convert `/Date(1422815400000)/` to a proper date format?

This is the code of the controller.js file which return data

```
for (i = 0; i < emp1.data.length; i++) {
                if (date == emp1.data[i].Date) {
                    if (emp1.data[i].InOut == 'I') {

                        temp = temp + " In : " + emp1.data[i].Time;
                    }
                    else {
                        temp = temp + " Out : " + emp1.data[i].Time;
                    }
                }
                else {

                    var newDate = Date.parse((emp1.data[i - 1].Date).toString());


                    modifyArray.push({
                        "EmployeeName": emp1.data[i - 1].EmployeeName, "Date": emp1.data[i - 1].Date,
                        "InOut": temp, "Hours": emp1.data[i - 1].Hours
                    });

                    temp = "";
                    date = emp1.data[i].Date;

                }

            }
$scope.EmployeesData = modifyArray;
```

Comment: In what format do you require it to be? You're currently parsing it as string yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There's a special date filter in AngularJS to change for displaying dates.

> In HTML Template Binding
>
> `{{ date_expression | date : format : timezone}}`
>
> In JavaScript
>
> `$filter('date')(date, format, timezone)`

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Answer (score -1):

What you are getting is a Unix timestamp, you can make a normal date of it using

```
var date = new Date(timestamp)
```

in your case:

```
var date = new Date(1422815400000)
```

Comment: It works for me but it give result like "2015-02-01T18:30:00.000Z" ca i convert it to dd/MM/yyyy format??

Comment: Yes, you can using: date.getDate() + '/' + date.getMonth() + '/' + date.getFullYear(). Take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp for more info.

Comment: Although this works, it's better to use the built-in angular date filter because it's less verbose and easier to write, read and maintain.